# iOS (Swift): Collection View indexPath(for: cell) is nil for non visible cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIViewController` that populates a `UICollectionView` with an array of type `Object`:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let objects: [Object]!

    weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func object(for cell: MyCell) {
        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { fatalError("No cell at index path") }
    }

}
```

The `collectionView` cells are represented by:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        super.apply(layoutAttributes)

        let obj = self.delegate?.object(for: self)
        // configure various subviews with obj ...

    }
}
```

which has a `delegate` that talks to `MyViewController` to get the `Object` instance that is representing:

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func object(for cell: MyCell) -> Object
}
```

This works fine when I scroll down between cells however, it crashes at `guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) ...` for cells that are off the screen when the `apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes)` method is called.

Is there a way to fix this? The cells need to know which instance of `Object` they are representing so that the view controller can tweak the model.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Your `cellForItemAt` should be passing the data to the cell. The cell should not be asking its delegate for data.

Comment: The thing is that cells are constantly being reused and recycled. That’s what the dequeue process is. It’s very common for a cell to be recycled and reused for a completely different index path. Always assume that if a cell is offscreen, then the collection view has already recycled it.

Comment: On a separate note, I would also say that you could change your delegate method to use the index path as the parameter, since the layout attributes already have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always assume that if a cell is offscreen, then the collection view has already recycled it. The collection view constantly does this to keep memory usage low and performance high.

To perform some action offscreen, what I often do is hold a separate object (view model, in MVVM) that a visible cell can attach to. This object is owned and retained by my objects and is never recycled. If I need to do any offscreen action, this object does it.

The cell’s only jobs are:

1. to display data and
2. receive user input

Both of those require it to be visible.

When I create cells, I use `prepareForReuse` to detach it from the previous view model and do necessary clean up before attaching the cell to the next one.

**Alternate Solution**

If all you need is the index path to get your special object, you could simply use the index path from the layout attributes.

```
protocol MyCellDelegate: class {
    func object(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Object
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var delegate: MyCellDelegate?

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        super.apply(layoutAttributes)

        let obj = self.delegate?.object(for: layoutAttributes.indexPath)
        // configure various subviews with obj ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Never call `prepareForReuse` yourself. Override it in your custom cell but do not write code that actually calls it directly.

Comment: I’ve never seen it get called without calling it myself.

Comment: @ABeard89 Thanks for all your answers/suggestions to my questions. Re: MVVM, so do you never have a method like `func configure(for person: Person) { self.nameLabel = person.name } ` inside your `UICollectionViewCell`, which is called by the `UIViewController` in `cellForItemAt`, for e.g.?

Comment: I have functions like that, sure. But the only things in the function are setting images / text strings and setting up callbacks to user input. Those callbacks only forward user input to other objects. The main idea is that the cell doesn’t do anything complicated, and it doesn’t need anything other than what is passed into that function.

Comment: @Alex Personally, I’ve begun to like FRP, so I use `ReactiveSwift` to bind views to view models (but that’s just personal preference), and the method that does that only links labels and such to the view model’s inputs and outputs. I think of all views as transient windows to/from my objects, which is where all the difficult stuff is done. When the view is on screen, I tell it what to display; when it’s not on screen, I don’t need it.

Comment: Old thread, but @rmaddy is correct. I don't know why I wasn't seeing it called before, but UIKit does automatically call `prepareForLayout`, so I edited my answer to be more correct.